# i am trying to run broadleaf admin it gives the following error

Tags: admin, broadleaf-commerce, solar

65761K of 142888K >>  2017-09-07 18:17:10.581 ERROR 8184 --- [           main] c.b.solr.autoconfigure.SolrServer        : Unable to download solr. If you need to connect through a proxy, the 'solr.dowload.proxyHost', 'solr.download.proxyPort', 'solr.download.proxyUserName' and 'solr.download.proxyPassword' properties are available. Also, make sure the user running this application has write priveleges to the download directory C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-5.3.1. A different download directory may be specified via the 'solr.server.workingDirectory' property.

Comment: Offtopic, there's a typo error in 'solr.dowload.proxyHost' in source code itself, it should be 'solr.download.proxyHost'.

Answer (score 3):

During the reference implementation startup, the system will attempt to download Solr, install it and launch it on your behalf. Solr is a required component and fulfills search functionality.

From what you've provided, it looks like something failed part way through the download. There should have been an additional stack trace that would provide additional information on the specific nature of the fault. Nonetheless, something happened midway through the download (network failure, something). You have several options:

1. Try deleting the `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-5.3.1` directory and try starting again. See if on a second attempt the download is successful. If this works, the download problem must have been temporary.

OR,

2. Download solr yourself from http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/5.3.1/solr-5.3.1.zip (it looks like you're on windows, so the zip file is appropriate). Expand the zip to the `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-5.3.1` directory. Now try starting again. This time, the system will detect you already have a solr installation and should skip the download step.

Comment: The `bin` folder of solr should be in this location: `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-5.3.1\solr-5.3.1\bin`